# Is there any R function that visualize the interaction effect of IV regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, plm, marginal-effects

I'm looking for a function for interaction effects visualization which has a correspondence with *ivreg* or *plm*. My model is 2sls with fixed effects but it seems there are no packages available for calculating interaction effects in R.

I'd be pleased if someone could solve my concern.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at `interplot()`. You can use this function to visualize e.g. the estimated coefficient of regressor `X` on outcome `Y` conditional on values of instrument `Z` by simply plugging in the fitted values from `ivreg()`. (The confidence intervals are trickier, but you are probably less interested in those in the first instance.)

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interplot/vignettes/interplot-vignette.html

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestion. But yes, confidence intervals become the issue. I will run regressions for the moment.

Comment: interplot() does nsot work with plm: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sim’ for signature ‘"plm"’